# Mockito: How to mock javax.inject.Provider-created prototype beans?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have a singleton Spring bean which creates prototype beans; those are retrieved from a `javax.inject.Provider` field:

```
@Component
public class MySingleton {
    @Autowired
    private javax.inject.Provider<MyPrototype> prototypeFactory;

    public void doStuff() {
        MyPrototype bean = prototypeFactory.get();
        bean.invoke();
    }
}

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class MyPrototype {
    public void invoke() {}
}
```

Now I would like to create a JUnit-Test for the Singleton:

```
@Mock 
MyPrototype prototype;
@InjectMocks 
MySingleton sut;
@Test
public void testPrototype() {
    sut.doStuff();
    verify(prototype, times(1)).invoke();
}
```

But that understandably doesn't properly setup the Singleton's `Provider`.

Is there any way to do that? I'd like to avoid creating a Singleton Factory bean which creates the Prototype instances.

Or, would it maybe be elegantly possible using a `@Lookup`-factory method for the Singleton? I haven't looked into that at all yet.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would stub that `Provider` and make it return the `prototypeMock` every time using the `@Before` method invoked before each of the tests:

```
@Mock
private javax.inject.Provider<MyPrototype> prototypeFactoryStub;
    
@Mock 
MyPrototype prototypeMock;

@InjectMocks 
MySingleton sut;

@Before
public void init(){
   MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); // optional

   when(prototypeFactoryStub.get()).thenReturn(prototypeMock);
}

@Test
public void testPrototype() {
    sut.doStuff();
    verify(prototypeMock, times(1)).invoke();
}
```

Comment: This solution also works for Spring's [ObjectProvider](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ObjectProvider.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
@Mock 
MyPrototype prototype;

@Spy
Provider<MyPrototype> prototypeProvider = new Provider<MyPrototype>() {
    public MyPrototype get() {return prototype;}
};

@InjectMocks 
MySingleton sut;
```